# How to validate a p12 and a mobileprovision file used to codesign an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, code-signing, codesign

I have a tool to compile iOS apps given some configurations, a mobileprovision file and a p12 file (pkcs12) with the certificate and the key used to create that mobileprovision.

The way it works now I'll only know this two files are invalid after compiling.

How I can test if this two files are valid and will work to codesign an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for some other validation of p12 file and I found script thats could help: https://gist.github.com/carsonmcdonald/9966912